# Unix Bash script: Using sort -n for a group of variables

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

I've found lots of help with the sort command on this site, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use it with variables. Basically, I have two (or more) variables and I want to echo the results in ascending order.

```
!#usr/bin/bash
# Look for PNG files
pngTotal=0
for i in /home/*
do
j=`grep -q PNG $i`
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
#echo "add 1 to png"
((pngTotal++))
fi
done
echo "PNG: $pngTotal"

# Look for GIF files
gifTotal=0
for i in /home/*
do
j=`grep -q GIF $i`
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
#echo "add 1 to gif"
((gifTotal++))
fi
done
echo "GIF: $gifTotal"
```

I want to list the variables of my pngTotal, gifTotal, etc. in ascending order. I tried different syntax along the lines of `sort -n $pngTotal $gifTotal` with no success.

Comment: Your shebang is actually a bangshe

Comment: Sample input, sample output required.

Comment: ummmm ... what on earth are you trying to do in your script??  I understand that you would seem to have files which may not have the correct extension or that you don't trust that so you want to see if the file is a png or not, but you could grep a text file with the letters PNG in it but clearly that will not be a png file.  Have a look at the file command and specifically the -b and --mime-type options.  I would also mention that if you were using the grep, you can actually pass that straight to the 'if' command

Comment: @grail It's for learning purposes. In case you're a bit daft to notice this is a beginner question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but if you don't mind writing the result to a temp file, you can do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Look for PNG files
pngTotal=0
for i in /home/*
do
j=`grep -q PNG $i`
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
#echo "add 1 to png"
((pngTotal++))
fi
done
echo "PNG: $pngTotal" >> /tmp/total.log

# Look for GIF files
gifTotal=0
for i in /home/*
do
j=`grep -q GIF $i`
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
#echo "add 1 to gif"
((gifTotal++))
fi
done
echo "GIF: $gifTotal" >> /tmp/total.log

sort -k2 -n /tmp/total.log
rm /tmp/total.log
```

You basically output the results to a file, and then sort it based on the second column (default separator is space), and then it being sorted ascending based on the numeric value.

Comment: This is a perfect solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- The actual problem you seem to try to solve can be solved with a one-liner, which will count all image files in your `home`, not only GIFs and PNGs:

  ```
  find /home/ -type f -print0 \
    | xargs -0L10 file -b --mime-type \
    | fgrep image/  \
    | cut -d/ -f2 \
    | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1n
  ```

  It works this way: collect all file names (`find`), have `xargs` pass them to `file` in order to find their mime type, filter out non-images with `fgrep`, remove the string `"image/"` by means of `cut`, count how many there are for each type with `sort|uniq -c` and finally sort the result numerically.
- The general problem of sorting the output of a piece of code can be solved with a subshell:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  ( 
    # Any command you like...
    echo "PNG: 3829"
    # Other commands
    echo "GIF: 233"
  ) | sort -k2,2n
  ```